# "minutes work" by users. How to make this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with this format:

```
id, user, action, date
1, user1, a1, 2013-03-20 10:00:01
2, user2, a1, 2013-03-20 10:00:03
3, user2, a1, 2013-03-20 10:00:12
4, user3, a1, 2013-03-20 10:00:20
5, user2, a1, 2013-03-20 10:00:24
....
...
```

and go on on all minutes and hours (24x7) with 30 differents users...

Now I need to know "minutes work"... for example:

1. if I have only one user on all day, I have 24h*60m = 1440 minutes
   work today.
2. If be 2 users in all day (24h) will be: 2880 minutes
   work...

but... the users dont work all day (of course..) how I can make this query?

**Answers to some Questions:**

- I need to get the minutes work by all users (sum of minutes from all
  user)
- I asume the "logout" of user if they dont make any action in 5 minutes.
- I can use some PHP code to make this work.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you just want to sum all the minutes in which a given user worked at least once?

Comment: So you have a table recording all their actions? How do you define when a user has stopped working then? If they haven't performed an action in, say 30 minutes perhaps? Or perhaps the time span between the first and last action on any given day?

Comment: Thanks for all comments... I edit the question to answer.

Comment: I don't think you mention it explicitly, but I am assuming you want to calculate work per user *per day*, is that correct?

Comment: Add what queries you tried or have this closed

Answer (score 1):

This query does it.

```
SELECT user, CAST(date AS DATE) day, (SUM(worked_seconds) / 60) minutes
FROM (
      SELECT    w1.user
      ,         w1.date
      ,         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
                  LEAST(
                    MIN(IFNULL(w2.date, w1.date + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)),
                    CAST(w1.date AS DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                  )
                )
                - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(w1.date) worked_seconds 
      FROM      work w1
      LEFT JOIN work w2
      ON        w1.user = w2.user
      AND       w1.date < w2.date
      AND       w1.date + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE > w2.date
      AND       CAST(w1.date AS DATE) = CAST(w2.date AS DATE)
      GROUP BY  w1.user, w1.date
) work
GROUP BY user, day
```

The query pairs each work row with all later work rows of the same user (ON w1.user = w2.user) within a 5 minute interval (AND w1.date < w2.data AND w1.date + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE > w2.date), provided the work occurred on the same day (CAST(w1.date AS DATE) = CAST(w2.date AS DATE).

By definition, there will be no later row for the last row on a particular day, and because we're using LEFT JOIN this will result in a NULL value. We assume that for that last row, 5 minutes of work were done as per the logout rule (IFNULL(w2.date, w1.date + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)

It is possible that for each (date, user) row multiple later rows are found, in which case we want to find the earliest one so we can calcualte the difference between the two dates. This is done using the MIN function.

Now, since the last row +  the 5 minute interval could extend beyond the end of the day, we use LEAST to prevent that.

The UNIX_TIMESTAMP's are there to convert datetimes to seconds, so we can easily substract them and get the number of worked seconds.

In the outer query, finally we SUM the work per user and divide by 60 in order to get from seconds to minutes.